# kubernetes client-go: convert labelselector to label string

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

In the kubernetes client-go API (or another library that uses it), is there a utility function to convert a `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/LabelSelector` to a string to fill the field `LabelSelector` in `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/ListOptions`?

I digged through the code of `client-go` but I can't find a function like that.

The `LabelSelector.Marshall()` nor `LabelSelector.String()` give me that (unsurprisingly, because that's not their purpose, but I tried it anyway).

#### Background

I have spec descriptions like `k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1/Deployment`, and want to use it's set of selector labels (i.e. the `Selector` field) to query it's pods using

```
options := metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: <stringified labels>,
}

podList, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(<namespace>).List(options)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `LabelSelectorAsMap(LabelSelector)` function to convert the labelselector into `map[string]string` map.

Then, use `SelectorFromSet` function of package `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels` to convert `map` to selector/strings.

Pseudo code:

```
import (
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func ListPod(labelSelector metav1.LabelSelector) {

    labelMap := metav1.LabelSelectorAsMap(labelSelector)

    options := metav1.ListOptions{
        LabelSelector: labels.SelectorFromSet(labelMap).String(),
    }

    podList, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("<namespace>").List(options)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done more directly with the following, rather than two conversions.

```golang
options := metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: metav1.FormatLabelSelector(deployment.Spec.Selector),
}
```

Reference https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#FormatLabelSelector